# Pack box inside "smaller" box

Tags: problem-solving, packing-problem

Now, there is a puzzle that is quite well known as far as I know, concerning the packing of rectangular boxes in 3-dimensional space. You also have a measurement of a box as the sum of the hight, width and length.

Now, I have read a proof that a bigger box, using this measurement, can be packed inside a smaller box. I do, however, remember that proof to be quite abstract. Is there a known example? Or is it just that I do not remember correctly, and it is actually impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement is somewhat unclear. I interpret it as follows: To every rectangular box, you assign the sum of its three dimensions as a measure of its "size". You then ask whether a box of greater "size" can be packed inside a box of lesser "size".

If you allow cutting up the box of greater "size", the answer is yes. For instance, a box with dimensions $3\times3\times3$ has "size" $9$ and volume $27$, whereas a box with dimensions $1\times4\times5$ has "size" $10$ and volume $20$, so you can cut the "bigger" one up, for instance into $20$ unit cubes, and pack it into the "smaller" one.

If cutting isn't allowed, this isn't possible. This is proved rather elegantly in Section 9 of [this article](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/solutions.pdf). The basic idea is to consider the volume of space at a distance at most $\epsilon$ from the box. This has contributions in various powers of $\epsilon$, stemming from the various rounded bits surrounding the box, and the leading contribution that depends on the box dimensions is due to the quarter-cylinders parallel to each of the edges. This goes as $\epsilon^2$ times the sum of the box dimensions. Since for any given $\epsilon$ the inner box augmented by $\epsilon$ lies within the outer box augmented by $\epsilon$, this leading contribution can't be bigger for the inner box than for the outer box, and thus the "size" of the inner box can't exceed that of the outer box.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, even when tilting the interior box.

This is question 70 (Airline Luggage) of *[The art of mathematics: coffee time in Memphis](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_art_of_mathematics.html?id=ButlynVk25MC)* by Béla Bollobás, where he proves twice over two pages the assertion

> Let $l(B)=a+b+c$ be the linear measure of an $a\times b\times c$ box 
>   (rectangular parallelepiped).
>   This linear measure is monotone in the sense that if a box $B$ is
>   contained in a box $C$ then $l(B) \le l(C).$

A superficially similar question, with a different answer, is [Prince Rupert's Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Rupert%27s_cube), where a cube of side 1.06 can pass through a hole in a cube of side 1.