# Is there a term that means "the sum of the length, width, and height of a box"?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I seem to encounter this sum every time I fly (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88898/72174), [airline baggage restrictions](http://www.westjet.com/guest/en/travel/basics/baggage/checked.shtml)) and am using it to limit the acceptable size of an object in an [RFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_proposal).  I have heard a variety of names for it, all of which sounded incorrect to me (e.g. Air Canada [calls this sum "linear dimensions"](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/airport/baggage/checked.html)).

Is there a less verbose term for this sum?

Comment: "The weird way airlines measure sizes of baggage for the purpose of setting limits" or such?

Comment: hmm...but that's _more_ verbose :)

Comment: I have a feeling this is more pragmatic than mathematical. There will be a high correlation between volume and sum of dimensions for carry-on bags. It is easier to measure the edges than to design a machine that measures the volume of each bag.

Answer (score 1):

It's the taxicab norm! It's two words, one to give the purpose of the tool and the other to distinguish it from other ways of providing such a description. It's not evocative, though. It's called linear because the equation a+b+c is straight if a, b, and c are variables, instead of curved. But I wouldn't think of it that way. I would think of combinatorics, or convexity. Packing things together and needing only a dimension that bleeds the pieces in an indistinct combination. Hence, I would think of it as the taxicab norm (since the dimensions are all-positive).

Comment: And I'm saying "linear measure" is less evocative because while it reminds you of the formula, it doesn't describe the way of thinking that leads you to use that measure.

Answer (score 1):

For rectangles, this would be the semiperimeter.  That term has no meaning for more than two dimensions, so perhaps we could just adopt it for this purpose.  :-)